# Force execution in main thread in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Dart program I am using the camera:

```
...    
final File imageProduct =  await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, maxHeight: 1024, maxWidth: 1024);
...
```

In previous version it worked well, now after a Flutter upgrade (v1.7.8+hotfix.3) the camera interface is displayed, I can take the photo, after that I get error:

```
W/Binder  ( 7331): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
W/Binder  ( 7331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: Binder:7331_4
```

In Flutter asynchronous functions are executed in main thread so I really don't understand what could be the problem.
I couldn't find an explicit way to force execution in main thread.

What could be the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34774

Comment: Thanks, it was only a version issue...

Answer (score 2):

1. Change flutter channel to dev (flutter channel dev). (U can omit this step)
2. run flutter upgrade
3. Change version of ImagePicker to latest one 0.6.3+1.
4. Run project

Issue is solved.

Comment: This solution works, version upgrade of imagepicker solves the issue. For me, it only required step 3 and reloading the project though. No flutter upgrade required.